# Zend Studio 8 - how to keep the project expanded?

Tags: zend-studio

At restart the PHP explore project is collapsed. I cannot find any setting to keep it from collapsing each time I restart. The window has only a "collapse all" functionality. For a deeply branched project is really useful to start where you left from, like in Netbeans.